# XML Reading Error for Data Table: There are multiple root elements at line x position x [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, datatable, stream, deserialization

I have a byte array in SQL and I want it in a data table in my app. The method below works fine the first three time but the fourth time it throws and error :
 **"Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 4812, position 20."**

```
 Dim xmlStreamAP2 As New IO.MemoryStream(APArray2)
    xmlStreamAP2.Seek(0, 0)
    Dim testStreamAP2 As New IO.MemoryStream
    Using df_fs = (New BinaryFormatter).Deserialize(xmlStreamAP2)
        testStreamAP2 = df_fs
        testStreamAP2.Seek(0, 0)
        apDT.Clear()
        apDT.ReadXml(testStreamAP2)
    End Using
```

apDt is my data table.

Comment: Could you post the xml you are using as well?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. The issue was that I wasnt clearing the memory stream after writing it somewhere and the next time I used it, it concatenated the new data with previous one. Now, I use the **new** to refresh it everytime before using. Thank you.

Comment: I know this is late, but you should include a code example with your answer.